# Excel non VBA Array changing cell solution

Tags: arrays, excel, cell

Ok so I ahve too worksheets and I am pulling in data from one worksheet to another I am using array in the form

```
=TRANSPOSE('Z:\MI 2015\[MIdata.xlsx]Capital'!F452:F462)
```

Now I my VBA is password protected and to be honest I don't want use VBA

The cells change every 11th cell(from first elememt) for range 10 cells long in array for next row in worksheet to pulled out e.g.

```
 =TRANSPOSE('Z:\MI 2015\[MIdata.xlsx]Capital'!F463:F473)
```

is next row in worksheet and so forth in that fashion.

So how can I run a loop to update new cell references to automate this data extract?

Comment: What do you mean by "run a loop" in the sense that you say you don't want to use VBA?

Comment: Well the cell needs an update  do cell=cell+11 for next position.

Comment: There may be a simple non-VBA solution but I'm afraid it isn't clear what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could post a very small example dataset together with expected results.

Comment: I was thinking of =TRANSPOSE('Z:\MI 2015[MIdata.xlsx]Capital'!F452:F462) then a loop where cell position is fisrt element in array F452 so +11 to next do for 'x' rows in worksheet. Basically something to update the new position . so F452 is now F 463:F473 and then F474:484 as these are the array columns pulling into my new rows in new worksheet. Does that make sense? thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a simple worksheet formula, e.g. =INDEX(Capital!$F$452:$F$1048576,10*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+COLUMNS($A:A)) in your first cell of choice, copied to the right a further 9 cells and also down?

Comment: ok tried that it works fine for across the rows using =INDEX('Z:\MI 2015\[MIdata.xlsx]Capital'!$F441:$F451,10*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+COLUMNS($A:A))

Comment: Are you saying that you have a solution? Why have you amended the range to one of simply 11 rows?

Comment: however the next row is =INDEX('Z:\MI 2015\[MIdata.xlsx]Capital'!$F442:$F452,10*(ROWS($1:2)-1)+COLUMNS($A:A))   and I want    =INDEX('Z:\MI 2015\[MIdata.xlsx]Capital'!$F452:$F462,10*(ROWS($1:2)-1)+COLUMNS($A:A))? thanks

Comment: i meant ok tried that it works fine for across the colums not rows earleir using...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The first return of the formula I posted will be the value in Capital!F452. When copied to the right, the results will be the values in Capital!F453, Capital!F454, etc., until we reach Capital!F461. And when the original formula is copied down, it will give the value in Capital!F462, Capital!F472, etc. Hence, copying both across and down produces a 10-column-by-x-row matrix of results, where x is the number of rows you choose to copy down.

Comment: ok got it working! with

Comment: =INDEX('Z:\MI 2015\[MIdata.xlsx]Capital'!$F$452:$F$1048576,11*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+COLUMNS($A:A))

Comment: out of curiosity where does $F$1048576 stem from?

Comment: 1048576 is 2^20, the number of rows in a (post-2003) Excel worksheet. Glad you got it working. It was 11, not 10, I see!

Comment: That formula would appear to be syntactically incorrect for what you are trying to achieve. For a start, the portion 52*(ROWS($1:1)-1) is not even within the INDEX formula. Please take more care when posting your actual formulas, first making sure that they are correct.